# When was the Quran (that is written in French language) written for the first time?

Tags: quran, history, bible, revelation, religion

I read in a introduction to the Coran I took at Ste-Foy public library, in the province of Quebec, in Canada, that it was not written for 200 years; after it was written on "banana leafs" and after on mud tablets. Nothing of that remain today, wrote the translator of the Coran I read in parts. I would like to know the date of the most ancient manuscript. My question has only a friendship intent. I asked the same for the Bible, including the Gospels and the letters of St-Paul. I received clear answers, especially for the letters of St Paul; but sometime "approximative" dates, especially for the books of the old Covenant of the Bible, for example "Isaie" (that is written I French language).

Comment: I've seen quran translations in Latin from the 16th century and some in German of one or two century later. I also know that Goethe read a first translation in German around the end of the 18th century. So i guess a French translation must have been made somewhere around the 17th century. Also note this is related to the history of French.

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you asking about the date of the earliest *arabic* manuscript of the Quran or the earliest *french* translation of it. The title implies the former and the body the latter. The answer to the first is that the sahabah had written manuscripts during the lifetime of the Prophet, later a compilation was made in the time of Abu Bakr and then Uthman. The answer to the second question is that *[L'Alcoran de Mahomet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Alcoran_de_Mahomet)* was  the earliest French translation of the Quran, done in 1647 CE.